# Django floppyforms OSMPointWidget does not display a map

Tags: python, django, openstreetmap, geodjango, django-floppyforms

I am trying to put an OSM-map, similar to the one in the geodjango-admin, into a form on my main site.

I decided to use floppyforms, set everything up like in the [documentation](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/geodjango.html) and it seems to get recognized, but strangely the map does not appear. Firebug shows that there is just an empty `<div id="id_coord_map"></div>` instead of the map, but it has all the right dimensions. The debug-textbox and the "Delete all features"-link are there like they should be. But, when I open the site, Firebug does not show any javascript requests in the 'network'-tab, so maybe that is a hint.

I guess I missed something or something isn't correctly included, but I tried for hours and really don't know anymore. Amongst other things I set all the paths for static files and run `manage.py collectstatic`, I also tried to not use the generic edit views, but it came out the same.

Here are the relevant parts in the code:

```
#views.py

import floppyforms as forms

...
class OSMPointWidget(forms.gis.PointWidget, forms.gis.BaseOsmWidget):
    pass

class LocationCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Location
    fields = ['name', 'zip', 'coord']
    form_class =  modelform_factory(Location,
        widgets={"coord": forms.gis.PointWidget(attrs = {
            'display_wkt': True,
            'map_srid':  4326,
            'map_width': 700,
            'map_height': 500,})})


#models.py

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='', unique=True)
    coord = models.PointField()
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='12345')
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Location, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


#urls.py

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r"location/$", views.LocationCreateView.as_view(),
        name = "locationcreate"),
    ...
)

#location_form.html

{% extends "_layouts/base.html" %}
{% block page_title %}Enter Location | {% endblock %}
{% block page_content %}
    <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}

#base.html

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block page_title %}{% endblock %}Calendar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap-theme.css" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>EVENTCALENDAR</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue and realised that I needed to include a {{ form.media }} tag in the header and then django-floppyforms supplies the relevant javascript files to make the map magically appear.

Somewhere in the **head** of base.html include a block for extra javascript

```
{% block extra_js %}{% endblock %}
```

Then fill in the block in your location_form.html

```
{% block extra_js %}
{{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}
```